# Is there any way to call yammer Rest api in SharePoint framework?

Tags: yammer, sharepoint-online

I want a code sample which explains , how to call a yammer rest api url in sharepoint framework.

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of any support planned for the SharePoint framework at this time, but the [Yammer JS SDK](https://developer.yammer.com/docs/js-sdk) may be usable [as an external JS library](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-docs/blob/master/docs/spfx/web-parts/guidance/use-existing-javascript-libraries.md). Since it's just JavaScript, it's more likely a limitation of the tooling or framework if it won't run. You will have trouble calling the REST APIs without using the SDK. It currently [lacks Typescript typings](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/issues/129) that you ideally would want to have. I'm not familiar enough with the SharePoint framework to know the best way to do this.